# jQuery mobile header disappears (becomes non-fixed) when another javascript action is hit

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a page that is served up with jQuery mobile.  In all of my mobile devices, when I press another link or image or any other javascript enabled element that uses a javascript event (like onclick), the header in my layout disappears.  It actually doesn't really disappear though, it just has it's position property changed to not be fixed.  when I scroll up to the top of my page, my header image is there and it scrolls with the rest of the page.  Then when I click another javascript enabled element on the page, it changes the header back to fixed again.

This behavior goes back and forth with any element I click on the page...really weird.

anyone else seen this?  Anyone know how to fix it?

here is my layout:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-add-back-btn="false">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <div style="text-align:left;padding-top:5px;padding-left:3px;">
                    <img src="/images/mylogo.png" alt="Logo" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                @{Html.RenderAction("Items", "Feedback", new {area=""});}
                @RenderBody()
            </div>

        </div>
```

TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but I had the same problem except that it happened no matter where and what I clicked.

I added `data-tap-toggle="false"` to the fixed element.

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

This is amazing. Has helped me in getting this fixed on an application. It was weird that it occurred on binding a class within the list options. When clicking any option in the list, the header and footer became movable and then on another click they became fixed.

Used the attribute  `data-tap-toggle="false"` as suggested by you in the `header` and the `footer` and it works like a charm. Thanks.